# Using multiple ASP Identity 2.0 within ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a web application with admin area for managing content but the rest of the site is currently secured by ASP Identity that authenticates my public users. Now I need to authenticate some internal users to access the admin area.

Is this possible?

Comment: where are the usernames and passwords for the admin area stored?

Comment: well, seems like you would have to have some intermediary class that held the join between the two databases, and the username and password from one database would need to be replicated into the other database.  Not easy, but not impossible.

Comment: So multiple = dual? And both sites are running under the same domain?

Comment: yes, example i have a site warheat1990.com, then I have a admin area for managing content for example warheat1990.com/admin, both have its own login and it is under same project/assembly in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is known as SSO (Single Sign On). With SSO a user can login once and access multiple applications. There are great articles on the web about the implementation. Have a look at http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc for a sample.